# How can I use web browser controls for non-browser game GUI?

Tags: c#, xna, monogame, gui, css

I'm looking for a way to get a modern browser's level of customization and rendering quality in my c# monogame to avoid using roundabout/limited/buggy GUI toolkits and to get better fonts without having to use pre-generated bitmap spritesheets (unicode support).

Is there a way to, for example, render a behind-the-scenes browser page instance onto a texture and overlay it above everything to act as GUI, along with all or just basic events (click, key press, hover, drag'n'drop)?

I've already tried using WinForms, but it's slow and most importantly, doesn't offer easy addition of custom controls which I'd very much like to use in my game. Otherwise I'd have to reimplement the whole thing in c#, but I'd rather not reinvent any wheels. For example, long lists, spreadsheets, flow controls with titles and descriptions for every item is a typical job for css, but not for WinForms.

And for the font part I'd like to get all the effects, which WinForms doesn't provide, and using the xna content pipeline, they have to be pre-baked in the bitmap font, which makes it insane to try to do dynamic font effects.

I understand that such great functionality might come at a great processing cost, but I think it's really gonna be worth the precision and font quality.

Comment: http://www.awesomium.com/ <- meets your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered trying to implement WPF instead of Winforms?

I've not personally attempted to get either Monogame or XNA working with WPF, but it does seem to be doable: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nicgrave/2010/07/25/rendering-with-xna-framework-4-0-inside-of-a-wpf-application/

WPF is a good deal better than Winforms in a lot of cases, especially when trying to add custom controls.